# Ant project imported incorrectly into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an Ant project set up. It compiles absolutely fine when run by Ant on the command line. When I import the project into Eclipse using New > Other > From Ant Buildfile, it can't understand the package structure.

I currently have the following Maven like structure:

```
 Root
   src
     main
       java
         projectcode
     test
       java
         projectcode
```

But when I import, it complains that it cannot find the files because the package name do not include "main.java". This is a legacy project and I'd rather not change the imports.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and select **Properties** and **Java Build Path**. Then select the **Source** tab and add `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` as source directories.